# Save and load User Control

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

So I am trying to build a WPF app and I ran into a bit of a scramble.

So I have the following code:

```
    <StackPanel Name="OfferStackPanel">
                    <TextBlock Name="OfferNameTextBlock"
                               Text=""
                               Margin="2,10,2,10"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               TextAlignment="Center"
                               FontSize="20"
                               MaxWidth="800"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                    <StackPanel Name="SuppliersStackPanel"
                        MinWidth="1302"
                        MaxWidth="1302"
                ></StackPanel>
                    <Image x:Name="Logo" 
                           HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="logo.ico"
                           MaxWidth="100"
                           Margin="20,20,10,20"
                           />
</StackPanel>
```

and

```
<Grid Name="SupplierUc">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="102"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="360*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="Producator"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   ></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Name="SupplierNameTextBox" 
            Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 FontStyle="Italic"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 FontSize="25"
                 MaxWidth="300"
                 Width="300"
                 Foreground="Red"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="0,3,0,3"
                 />
        <Button Name="AddCategoryButton"
                Click="AddCategoryUc"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                Grid.Row="1"
                FontSize="15"
                Height="30"
                MaxHeight="30"
                Width="130"
                MaxWidth="130"
                Content="Adauga Categorie"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Background="{x:Null}" 
                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                Foreground="#FF6270F5" Cursor="Hand"
                />

        <Button Name="DeleteSupplierRowButton"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="3"
                Content="Sterge Producator" 
                Background="{x:Null}" 
                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                Click="RemoveSupplierUc"
                Foreground="#FFF50F0F"
                Cursor="Hand"
            />
            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Name="CategoryPanel"
            ></StackPanel>
    </Grid>
```

and

```
<Grid Name = "CategoryUC">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="13"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="102"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="360*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Text="Categorie"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   ></TextBlock>
        <TextBox Name="CategoryNameTextBox"
                Grid.Column="2"
                 Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 FontSize="20"
                 VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                 MinWidth="300"
                 Width="Auto"
                 Foreground="Black"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 Margin="0,3,0,3"
                 />
        <Button Name="DeleteSupplierRowButton"
                Grid.Row="0"
                Grid.Column="4"
                Content="Sterge Categorie" 
                Background="{x:Null}" 
                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                Click="RemoveCategoryUc"
                Foreground="#FFF50F0F"
                Cursor="Hand"
            />
        <Button Name="AddOptionUcButton"
                Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Content="Adauga Optiune"
                Click="AddOptionUc"
                Height="20"
                Width="100"
                Background="{x:Null}" 
                BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                Foreground="Black"
                Cursor="Hand"
                Margin="1,1,1,1"/>
        <UniformGrid Grid.Row="2"
                     Columns="2"
                    Grid.Column="1"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                    ClipToBounds="True"
                    Name="OptionItems">
        </UniformGrid>
    </Grid>
```

So, when the user will interact with the UI, he will dinamically add several  SupplierUc to the OfferStackPanel and several CategoryUc to each SupplierUc.

I need to save the final OfferStackPanel and reload it into the project at any time, with the possibility to edit it.

Comment: This is a really bad way to do things in any environment, but particularly in WPF. You should be saving a collection of Suppliers and Categories, simple POCO classes which just carry the information. Save them as XML, DB records, JSON, or whatever. When you reload those later, instantiate viewmodels for them which are displayed in ItemsControls via DataTemplates. This is easy straightforward stuff using MVVM. What you're doing seems "simple" but I can tell you from experience, it will cause you a lot of pain.

Comment: It is a very good answer, however, there are more layers under the Categories UC and each one has a lot of dynamically generated data and if I would databind each and every one of them it would take me ages. I am restricted to not using database and I am looking at MVVM as the last approach possible at this point.

Comment: I'd say that what you're describing is tailor made for MVVM and storing the data in XML. Writing a few DataTemplates never took me ages. But if you've done it both ways in the past and you've found it easier to do it the way you're proposing, I won't argue. However, my own experience suggests that your plan is like choosing to drive through straight through a dense forest because the highway detours around it.

Answer (score 0):

That's what you are probably looking for :

[Creating and Loading XAML dynamically in WPF](http://www.devcurry.com/2010/08/creating-and-loading-xaml-dynamically.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ed actually gave me the idea to use POCO clases and I managed to do what I wanted by creating custom classes and mapping the information the user inputs to them and then serializing into xml files. When I load a file, I deserialize it in the models and then rebuild the elements with the data contained in the xml.